# How does webjars files get resolved as path

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, thymeleaf, webjars

I'm using spring mvc and spring boot to develop a web app and I have a question regarding webjars. To add the path of the webjar in thymeleaf, we do the following for example: `th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/...}"`

Now when I viewed the page source after being resolved by tomcat, the actual href  attribute in the link tag was: `href="/webjars/bootstrap/..."`

But looking at the directory structure of the web app in tomcat, there is no such files (couldn't find bootstrap.min.js inside of 3.3.6 inside of ... till we reach a webjars folder) .. instead the files are inside the jar file in the lib folder which is far away from the html file in the directory structure .. so how did it get resolved? isn't the href attribute supposed to reference files based on the current directory location of the html file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WebJars take advantage of the automatic static resource handling in Tomcat.  With Tomcat / Servlet 3, files on the CLASSPATH in a `META-INF/resources` directory are automatically exposed as static resources under the servlet context.  So if you have a jar on the CLASSPATH that contains `META-INF/resources/foo.txt` and your webapp is running in the root context, then that file will automatically be available at: `http://localhost:8080/foo.txt`

Since the Bootstrap WebJar has a file like:
`META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js`
It is available at:
`http://localhost:8080/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: How would I get bootstrap css if my webapp is something like http://localhost:8080/testexample/foo.txt. I am using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  and this is not working.

Comment: What server are you using? Did you add the WebJar to your build / classpath?

Comment: Yes I have. So my problem is if I use http://localhost:8080/foo.txt, bootstrap is loaded fine. But if I have something like http://localhost:8080/testexample/foo.txt , it is not working.

Comment: Maybe need an absolute path?